# Number to words in devnagri

Tags: php

I have to display result as 
दुई खर्ब सतासी अर्ब अन्ठान्नब्बे करोड नब्बे लाख बाह्र हजार तीन सय पचहत्तर ...
It displays result correctly till five numbers.. 
But it doesn't display as needed when we use six numbers.... 
like 111111 .... It displays "एक **सय** एघार हजार एक सय एघार" 
Where as it must be as "एक **लाख** एघार हजार एक सय एघार" .....
In case of seven and more numbers it throws error....
error 'Undefined offset: 1000000 in.....' ...

```
    <?php
   function convert_number_to_words($number) {

   $hyphen      = '-';
   $conjunction = '  ';
   $separator   = ' ';
   $negative    = 'negative ';
   $decimal     = ' point ';
   $dictionary  = array(
    0                   => 'शुन्य',
    1                   => 'एक',
    2                   => 'दुई',
    3                   => 'तीन',
    4                   => 'चार',
    5                   => 'पाँच',
    6                   => 'छ',
    7                   => 'सात',
    8                   => 'आठ',
    9                   => 'नौ',
    10                  => 'दश',
    11                  => 'एघार',
    12                  => 'बाह्र',
    13                  => 'तेह्र',
    14                  => 'चौध',
    15                  => 'पन्ध',
    16                  => 'सोह्र',
    17                  => 'सत्र',
    18                  => 'अठार',
    19                  => 'उन्नाइस',
    20                  => 'विस',
    21                  => 'एक्काइस',
    22                  => 'बाइस',
    23                  => 'तेइस',
    24                  => 'चौविस',
    25                  => 'पच्चिस',
    26                  => 'छब्बिस',
    27                  => 'सत्ताइस',
    28                  => 'अठ्ठाईस',
    29                  => 'उनन्तिस',
    30                  => 'तिस',
    31                  => 'एकत्तिस',
    32                  => 'बत्तिस',
    33                  => 'तेत्तिस',
    34                  => 'चौँतिस ',
    35                  => 'पैँतिस',
    36                  => 'छत्तिस',
    37                  => 'सैँतीस',
    38                  => 'अठतीस',
    39                  => 'उनन्चालीस',
    40                  => 'चालीस',
    41                  => 'एकचालीस',
    42                  => 'बयालीस',
    43                  => 'त्रियालीस',
    44                  => 'चवालीस',
    45                  => 'पैँतालीस',
    46                  => 'छयालीस',
    47                  => 'सरचालीस',
    48                  => 'अठचालीस',
    49                  => 'उनन्चास',
    50                  => 'पचास',
    51                  => 'एकाउन्न',
    52                  => 'बाउन्न',
    53                  => 'त्रिपन्न',
    54                  => 'चउन्न',
    55                  => 'पचपन्न',
    56                  => 'छपन्न',
    57                  => 'सन्ताउन्न ',
    58                  => 'अन्ठाउन्न',
    59                  => 'उनन्साठी',
    60                  => 'साठी',
    61                  => 'एकसट्ठी',
    62                  => 'बयसट्ठी',
    63                  => 'त्रिसट्ठी',
    64                  => 'चौंसट्ठी',
    65                  => 'पैंसट्ठी',
    66                  => 'छयसट्ठी',
    67                  => 'सतसट्ठी',
    68                  => 'अठसट्ठी',
    69                  => 'उनन्सत्तरी',
    70                  => 'सत्तरी',
    71                  => 'एकहत्तर',
    72                  => 'बहत्तर',
    73                  => 'त्रिहत्तर',
    74                  => 'चौहत्तर',
    75                  => 'पचहत्तर',
    76                  => 'छयहत्तर',
    77                  => 'सतहत्तर',
    78                  => 'अठहत्तर',
    79                  => 'उनासी',
    80                  => 'असी',
    81                  => 'एकासी',
    82                  => 'बयासी',
    83                  => 'त्रियासी',
    84                  => 'चौरासी',
    85                  => 'पचासी',
    86                  => 'छयासी',
    87                  => 'सतासी',
    88                  => 'अठासी',
    89                  => 'उनान्नब्बे',
    90                  => 'नब्बे',
    91                  => 'एकान्नब्बे',
    92                  => 'बयानब्बे',
    93                  => 'त्रियान्नब्बे',
    94                  => 'चौरान्नब्बे',
    95                  => 'पन्चानब्बे',
    96                  => 'छयान्नब्बे',
    97                  => 'सन्तान्नब्बे',
    98                  => 'अन्ठान्नब्बे',
    99                  => 'उनान्सय',
    100                 => 'सय',
    1000                => 'हजार',
    100000              => 'लाख',
    10000000            => 'करोड',
    1000000000          => 'अर्ब',
    100000000000        => 'खर्ब'
       );

        if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        return false;
        }

         if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - 
      PHP_INT_MAX) {

        trigger_error(
            'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . 
      PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
        E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return false;
       }

     if ($number < 0) {
      return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
      }

     $string = $fraction = null;

    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
     list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
    }

     switch (true) {
     case $number < 100:
        $string = $dictionary[$number];
        break;
     case $number < 100:
        $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
        $units  = $number % 10;
        $string = $dictionary[$tens];
        if ($units) {
            $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
        }
        break;
     case $number < 1000:
        $hundreds  = $number / 100;
        $remainder = $number % 100;
        $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;;
       default:
        $baseUnit = pow(100000, floor(log($number, 100000)));
        $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
        $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
        $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . 
       $dictionary[$baseUnit];
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
            $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;
      }

     if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
     $string .= $decimal;
     $words = array();
     foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
        $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
       }
       $string .= implode(' ', $words);
      }

      return $string;

      }

      ?>

      Page "numtoword.php"


      Page "index.php"
         <?php
        include('numword.php');
         echo convert_number_to_words(287989012375);

         ?>
```

Comment: I think there is not to many that can help you since we can't read it. But I advise you to search for Indian number to words conversion. There are lots of threads for that. I think you can use the logic from those answers.

Comment: Dear Amr Berag sir, I have edited question. Please help me... I have googled to solve it too, but failed to get any logics.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are making it more difficult than it needs to be. I created a simpler recursive function, moved the dictionary and settings outside the function (generating a dictionary array on every function call was eating up a LOT of memory and is not necessary). I didn't include fractions but this should be a good starting point to expand off of:

```php
<?php

$devnagriNumeralWords = [
    'dictionary' => [
        'smallUnits' => [
            0                   => 'शुन्य',
            1                   => 'एक',
            2                   => 'दुई',
            3                   => 'तीन',
            4                   => 'चार',
            5                   => 'पाँच',
            6                   => 'छ',
            7                   => 'सात',
            8                   => 'आठ',
            9                   => 'नौ',
            10                  => 'दश',
            11                  => 'एघार',
            12                  => 'बाह्र',
            13                  => 'तेह्र',
            14                  => 'चौध',
            15                  => 'पन्ध',
            16                  => 'सोह्र',
            17                  => 'सत्र',
            18                  => 'अठार',
            19                  => 'उन्नाइस',
            20                  => 'विस',
            21                  => 'एक्काइस',
            22                  => 'बाइस',
            23                  => 'तेइस',
            24                  => 'चौविस',
            25                  => 'पच्चिस',
            26                  => 'छब्बिस',
            27                  => 'सत्ताइस',
            28                  => 'अठ्ठाईस',
            29                  => 'उनन्तिस',
            30                  => 'तिस',
            31                  => 'एकत्तिस',
            32                  => 'बत्तिस',
            33                  => 'तेत्तिस',
            34                  => 'चौँतिस ',
            35                  => 'पैँतिस',
            36                  => 'छत्तिस',
            37                  => 'सैँतीस',
            38                  => 'अठतीस',
            39                  => 'उनन्चालीस',
            40                  => 'चालीस',
            41                  => 'एकचालीस',
            42                  => 'बयालीस',
            43                  => 'त्रियालीस',
            44                  => 'चवालीस',
            45                  => 'पैँतालीस',
            46                  => 'छयालीस',
            47                  => 'सरचालीस',
            48                  => 'अठचालीस',
            49                  => 'उनन्चास',
            50                  => 'पचास',
            51                  => 'एकाउन्न',
            52                  => 'बाउन्न',
            53                  => 'त्रिपन्न',
            54                  => 'चउन्न',
            55                  => 'पचपन्न',
            56                  => 'छपन्न',
            57                  => 'सन्ताउन्न ',
            58                  => 'अन्ठाउन्न',
            59                  => 'उनन्साठी',
            60                  => 'साठी',
            61                  => 'एकसट्ठी',
            62                  => 'बयसट्ठी',
            63                  => 'त्रिसट्ठी',
            64                  => 'चौंसट्ठी',
            65                  => 'पैंसट्ठी',
            66                  => 'छयसट्ठी',
            67                  => 'सतसट्ठी',
            68                  => 'अठसट्ठी',
            69                  => 'उनन्सत्तरी',
            70                  => 'सत्तरी',
            71                  => 'एकहत्तर',
            72                  => 'बहत्तर',
            73                  => 'त्रिहत्तर',
            74                  => 'चौहत्तर',
            75                  => 'पचहत्तर',
            76                  => 'छयहत्तर',
            77                  => 'सतहत्तर',
            78                  => 'अठहत्तर',
            79                  => 'उनासी',
            80                  => 'असी',
            81                  => 'एकासी',
            82                  => 'बयासी',
            83                  => 'त्रियासी',
            84                  => 'चौरासी',
            85                  => 'पचासी',
            86                  => 'छयासी',
            87                  => 'सतासी',
            88                  => 'अठासी',
            89                  => 'उनान्नब्बे',
            90                  => 'नब्बे',
            91                  => 'एकान्नब्बे',
            92                  => 'बयानब्बे',
            93                  => 'त्रियान्नब्बे',
            94                  => 'चौरान्नब्बे',
            95                  => 'पन्चानब्बे',
            96                  => 'छयान्नब्बे',
            97                  => 'सन्तान्नब्बे',
            98                  => 'अन्ठान्नब्बे',
            99                  => 'उनान्सय'
        ],
        'largeUnits' => [
            100                 => 'सय',
            1000                => 'हजार',
            100000              => 'लाख',
            10000000            => 'करोड',
            1000000000          => 'अर्ब',
            100000000000        => 'खर्ब'
        ]
    ],
    'hyphen'                => '-',
    'conjunction'           => '  ',
    'separator'             => ' ',
    'negative'              => 'negative ',
    'decimal'               => ' point '
];

function convert_devnagri_number_to_words($number) {
    global $devnagriNumeralWords;

    $numLen = strlen($number);
    $output = [ 'prefix' => '', 'base' => '', 'suffix' => '' ];

    $base = pow(10, $numLen-1);

    $smallestLargeUnit = array_keys($devnagriNumeralWords['dictionary']['largeUnits'])[0];

    $isNegative = $number < 0;
    if( $isNegative ) {
        $output['prefix'] .= $devnagriNumeralWords['negative'];
        $number = abs($number);
    }

    if( $number < $smallestLargeUnit ) {
        // Number is less than 100

        $prefix = $number;

    } else {
        // Get base amount (100, 1000, 100000, etc)

        if( isset($devnagriNumeralWords['dictionary']['largeUnits'][$base]) ) {
            $largeUnit = $devnagriNumeralWords['dictionary']['largeUnits'][$base];
        } else {
            // No exact large unit match, find next smallest
            while( $base >= $smallestLargeUnit ) {
                $base = (int) ($base / 10);
                if( isset($devnagriNumeralWords['dictionary']['largeUnits'][$base]) ) {
                    break; // Found a match!
                }
            }
        }

        $output['base'] .= $devnagriNumeralWords['dictionary']['largeUnits'][$base];

        // Get prefix, e.g. "28" when number is 28564
        $prefix = (int) ($number / $base);

        // Subtract prefix to get next part to process
        // E.g. the next number is 345 when the number is 85345
        $nextNumber = $number - ($prefix * $base);
        if( $nextNumber > 0 )
            $output['suffix'] = convert_devnagri_number_to_words($nextNumber);

    }

    if( $prefix >= 0 ) {
        $output['prefix'] .= $devnagriNumeralWords['dictionary']['smallUnits'][$prefix];
    }

    // Put it all together!
    return implode( $devnagriNumeralWords['separator'], array_filter($output) );

}

echo convert_devnagri_number_to_words(287989012375);
```

Comment: Glad I could help.